# Satoshi WordPress Theme - Portfolio SetUp Issues

Tags: themes

Hoping someone can assist but I am using the Satoshi WordPress theme (see:> http://www.vooshthemes.com/wordpress-theme/satoshi-2/ ) but I am having issues with creating a standalone page for my Portfolio page.

Basically, I have created a page called “Portfolio” and changed the template type to “Portfolio” and publish.

I then attempt to upload three images to this page based on the instructions (see> http://www.cedricarnold.com/blog/wp-content/themes/satoshi/instructions/instructions.html ) and am unable to do so. I can’t even get one image to display.

And from what I can see also, I am unsure how to upload multiple images onto this portfolio page as it mentions that I need to set the image as a ‘featured image’, doing this for the first image is fine but does not display but when I attempt to upload a second image to the portfolio page, my original image is overridden and so, cannot see how I can upload multiple images.

Can someone who has hopefully used this theme pls take me through the steps of say uploading 3 images with captions on the top onto my Portfolio page.

Would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by reading the instructions much more carefully, that comes with the theme.

FYI, my issue is clearly stated in the instructions under the heading of "Porfolio".

All good now.